# Using generic constraint kinds

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I can quite validly write a type like this in Haskell:

```
(t ~ (a, b)) => t
```

Which in a roundabout way says that `t` is some pair.

But lets say I want to do this:

```
type family MyConstraint t :: Constraint

data PairConstraintParam

type instance MyConstraint PairConstraintParam = ...

(t ~ MyConstraint PairConstraintParam) => t
```

What can I place after the `type instance MyConstraint PairConstraintParam =`

I tried `(a,b)` but GHC complained `a` and `b` were not on the RHS. It didn't seem to like `forall`s either.

This may seem like a silly example, there's potentially different constraints for different instances of a class, so hence this roundabout scheme. As the constraints affect and depend on parameters to a method in a class, I can't just place them in the instance head.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here - can you try to elaborate a bit?

Comment: You probably want something like `type family IsPair (x :: *) :: Constraint where IsPair (a,b) = ()`. You can go one further and extract the arguments immediately - `type family PairArgs (x :: *) :: Maybe (*,*) where PairArgs (a,b) = 'Just '(a,b); PairArgs x = 'Nothing`. In cases where you just want to know its a pair (like in your type family), you can write `IsJust (PairArgs t)`. When you want to get the args, you can write `PairArgs t ~ 'Just '(a,b)`. Kind of boring with pairs but generalizes quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the equality constraint here doesn't really make sense in that form. `~` should have a sort like `k -> k -> Constraint`, so `t` in that context would need to have kind `Constraint` on the left side, while on the right side you need to end with `*`...

However, if I have understood the problem correctly, you need to have existential type for `a` and `b`; so maybe this is what you want:

```
data PairConstraintParam

data ExistentialPair :: * where
  Exists :: (a, b) -> ExistentialPair

type family MyConstraint (p :: *) (t :: *) :: Constraint where
  MyConstraint PairConstraintParam t = t ~ ExistentialPair

test :: (MyConstraint PairConstraintParam t) => t
test = Exists (1, "hi")
```

Meaning that "there exist `a, b`, such that `t ~ (a, b)`" (up to isomorphism). Of course, you would want to add some more constraints to actually do something useful.

Another variant I can think of is the following:

```
data ConstraintVariant = PairConstraint

class IsPair p where
instance IsPair (a, b)

type family ConstrainedBy (c :: ConstraintVariant) :: * -> Constraint where
  ConstrainedBy PairConstraint = IsPair

data Thing c t where
  Thing :: (c t) => t -> Thing c t

test2 :: Thing (ConstrainedBy PairConstraint) (Int, String)
test2 = Thing (1, "hi")
```

Which lets you recover both the constraint and the underlying type.

Comment: The `ExistentialPair` type is not very useful.. you can't do anything with the values inside - you might as well store a `((), ())`. `data IsPair (x :: *) where IsPair :: (a,b) -> IsPair (a,b)` is probably actually useful

Comment: Sure it's not useful as is. But there wasn't more context, and I assumed that the need for adding more type context would be clear anyway, if one wants to use existentials in practise.